# Asynchronous method?

Tags: c#, multithreading, xamarin.ios

I need to make webservice calls asynchronously in Monotouch, as the UIAlertView only shows up after work was done.

Current code (pseudo)

```
Class LoginviewController
{
        void Login(credentials)  
        {  
            showAlert("Logging in") ;   
            bool authenticated = service.Authenticate(Credentials);  
        }
 }       

 class Service
 {
       Public bool Authenticate(object Credentials)
       {
          object[] results = this.Invoke("GetAuth", Credentials)
       }
 }
```

I am in the process of moving the Service methods to an async model, With Authenticate being made up of `BeginAuthenticate(), EndAuthenticate(), AuthenticateAsync(), OnAuthenticateOperationCompleted()` and of course `Authenticate()`.

When all of these have completed I need to run OnAuthenticateCompleted() on the LoginViewController, so I will use `BeginInvokeOnMainThread(delegate....`

This is where I get stuck.

How do I get the method `OnAuthenticateCompleted()` in LoginViewController class instance executed from the services class?

EDIT: Solution:

Added a OnAuthenticateCompleted event handler that is hooked up in Login(), and called the AuthenticateAsync() method instead of Authenticate().

```
Class LoginviewController
    {
            void Login(credentials)  
            {  
                showAlert("Logging in") ;   
                service.AuthenticateCompleted += new GetAuthenticationCompletedEventHandler(OnAuthenticateCompleted);
                service.AuthenticateAsync(Credentials);  
            }

            public void OnAuthenticateCompleted(obj sender, GetAuthenticationCompletedEventArgs args)
            {
                bool authenticated = (bool)args.Results;
                //do stuff
                hideAlert();
            }
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't execute `LoginViewController.OnAuthenticateCompleted` from the services class, you execute it in the completed event handler.

```
class LoginViewController
{
    void Login (credentials)
    {
        service.AuthenticateAsync (credentials, LoginCompletedCallback);
        }

    }
    void LoginCompletedCallback ()
    {
        BeginInvokeOnMainThread (OnAuthenticateCompleteded);
    }
}
```